# compare two tables and add result in second table

Tags: sql-server

I have been working on comparing two almost identical tables and update/add the result in second table. Here are the two tables i am using. *Person1*(ID,Name,PHNumber) and *Person2*(ID,Name,PHNumber,IsActive).

**Note:** person1 has always a more/less/same rows than person2.Person1 is reference table we need to add/delete the rows which does/doesnot present in person1 int to person2. *I am using microsoft SQL server management studio.*

**Case1:** If the compared result has more rows(Let say person1 has 10, person2 has 8rows) then we need to add those(2rows) to person2 and keep IsActive-1 for those rows.

**Case2:** If the compared result has differnce(Let say person1 has 10 but person2 has 20rows) then we need to find those delta 10rows and keep IsActive-0 for those 10rows.

Hope the query is clear and expecting your valuable solutions. Thank you.

```html
Here Person1 does not contain newdata2 and contains newdata,newdata1 which are 
new values after comparing, so we are giving IsActive-0 and IsActive-1 
respectively.
Person1:
   ID      Name      PHNumber
1 missouri     123
2 kansas       111
3 stlouise     234
4 california   456
5 india        888
6 srilanka     780
7 dallas       890
8 texas        1111
9 mario        1112
10 sister       7878
11 pontiac      8765
12 newdata      1234
13 newdata1     2345

Person2:
ID      Name      PHNumber   IsActive
1 missouri     123        1
2 kansas       111        1
3 stlouise     234        1
4 california   456        1
5 india        888        1
6 srilanka     780        1
7 dallas       890        1
8 texas        1111       1
9 mario        1112       1
10 sister       7878       1
11 pontiac      8765       1
12      newdata2     987        1

RESULT: Person2:
ID      Name      PHNumber   IsActive
1 missouri     123        1
2 kansas       111        1
3 stlouise     234        1
4 california   456        1
5 india        888        1
6 srilanka     780        1
7 dallas       890        1
8 texas        1111       1
9 mario        1112       1
10 sister       7878       1
11 pontiac      8765       1
12      newdata2     987        0
13      newdata      1234       1
14  newdata1     2345       1
```

Comment: Which matching columns (where the values in the columns are the same) make a row "equal" to another row?

Comment: This is very easy. Please try to use a merge/update statement and come back to us. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server?  You have both tagged... which do you mean?

Comment: @pmbAustin sorry i mean sql-server, could you please help me out for this query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still looking or answer, you can try like this...

```
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT
    COALESCE(p1.id, p2.id) AS id,
    COALESCE(p1.name, p2.name) AS name,
    COALESCE(p1.phnumber, p2.phnumber) AS phnumber,
    CASE WHEN p1.name IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsActive
FROM Person1 p1
FULL JOIN person2 p2
    ON p1.name = p2.name
    AND p1.phnumber = p2.phnumber)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id, phnumber) AS id,
    name, phnumber, IsActive
FROM cte
```

Comment: Thank you, Kannan Kndasamy, your solution gave me the correct result but i need to test in all cases. Thank you for spending your valuable time for me..